# How to replace append lines of in ABAP 7.5?

Tags: abap, internal-tables

I have the following code snippet, that I would like to write in functional style :

```
 data(lt_es) = me->prepare_process_part_ztoa1( ).
 APPEND LINES OF me->prepare_process_part_protocol( ) to lt_es.
```

How to rewrite the code above in new ABAP 7.5?

Comment: Indeed, appending lines returned from one method to lines on second method of the same class is a bad architecture, this logic can be merged into single one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`LINES OF`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenvalue_constructor_params_lspc.htm) construct (available since [ABAP 7.40 SP 8](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_740_index_htm/7.40/en-US/abennews-740_sp08-expressions.htm#!ABAP_MODIFICATION_6@6@)).

For instance, it could be something like this:

```
lt_es = VALUE #( BASE me->prepare_process_part_ztoa1( )
                 ( LINES OF me->prepare_process_part_protocol( ) ) ).
```

Whether it is better/simplier than the original, that's another question :)

Answer (score 2):

It can be also done without `BASE`. However one must specify the type explicitly (usage of `#` ends with a syntax error).

```
REPORT ZZZ.

DATA: lt_t1 TYPE string_table,
      lt_t2 TYPE string_table.

DATA(lt_t3) = VALUE string_table( ( LINES OF lt_t1 ) ( LINES OF lt_t2 ) ).
```

Would be interesting to know if this is maybe more performant than the usage of `BASE` if used in a loop for example.

Comment: See [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/09/29/abap-news-for-740-sp08-start-value-for-constructor-expressions/#comment-82547). Seems like LINES OF really makes a copy, while BASE bascially is a move.